# Issue positioning a position: absolute element in Tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm working on this `TailwindCSS` project where I have a logo to the left and navigation to the right. Both of them are centered. Because the logo is `position:absolute;` the navigation is behind the logo. I want them to be side by side. I'm using `flex`. Is it possible? I'm not sure if `grid` will be a better solution.

This is the link to [tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2TvxcyP0g3?layout=horizontal).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to apply `padding-right` to the logo.

Change this...

```
<span class="logo flex items-center">...</span>
```

...to this.

```
<span class="logo flex items-center pr-10">...</span>
```

[image]

See the [snippet](https://play.tailwindcss.com/bI2UZ1oEUY?layout=horizontal).

Comment: Change it to ```pr-32```, there is also a link to "home" behind the logo ;)

Comment: I tried margin and padding before and it didn't work. The thing is that I have done so many tweaks to it that I lost track!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to put the logo inside the `<ul>...</ul>` inside an extra list (`<li>`) item. This way it will allways be next to your homepage link, and won't overlap. You will have to add the width of the image to the `<li>` element.

An example is seen here:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/NlxxGIsX1v?layout=horizontal

Comment: Jeremy, it'll be turn into a WordPress theme later:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>`. I want to isolate the logo from the menu. 